# Textbox disable when change width css

Tags: html, css

i have a website, my website is [link](http://103.253.113.37/bubble_apps/web/)

i create textbox and button, but this textbox and button disable. i not put disable javascript disable in textbox and button :(

this is part of code

```
<section style="margin-left:0%;width:74.3%" class="b-infoblock b-bg-block-mobile b-product-launch">
              <div  class="row b-infoblock--without-border">
                <div style="margin-left:5%">
                  <h1  class="c-white f-primary-b f-title-bigger">Community is in Your Hand</h1>
                  <div class="b-product-info b-shortcode-example">
                    <h3 class="f-primary-l c-white f-title-big b-default-top-indent">now available <br/> for Android</h3>
                    <div>
                        <a style="width:225px;background: rgb(114, 190, 88) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;color:white;float:left" class="b-btn-special f-btn-special c-white" href="apk/Markisha.apk">
                            <i class="fa fa-download b-left"></i>
                            <p><span>Free Forever</span><br/><strong class="f-primary-b f-uppercase">Download Now</strong></p>
                        </a>

                        <div style="background: rgb(114, 190, 88) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;color:white;margin-left:10px" class="b-btn-special f-btn-special c-white"> 
                            <p><strong class="f-primary-b f-uppercase">Send Apps To Email</strong></p>
                                <div>
                                    <form id="form-upload" method="POST">
                                        <input type="text" style="color:black" name="email"> 
                                        <button class="b-btn-special f-btn-special c-white" type="submit">SEND NOW</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            <center>
                                <font color="green" id="success"></font>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </section>
```

But when i change width

```
<a style="width:225px;background: rgb(114, 190, 88) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;color:white;float:left" class="b-btn-special f-btn-special c-white" href="apk/Markisha.apk">
```

to

```
<a style="width:220px;background: rgb(114, 190, 88) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;color:white;float:left" class="b-btn-special f-btn-special c-white" href="apk/Markisha.apk">
```

i can input text, and klik button. but this button change like this

[image]

Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section with class `b-infoblock` is coming on top of the input. Use below css to clear it.

```
.b-infoblock{
   margin-top: 0 !important
   clear: both;
}
```